# How can I generate documentation from my SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I have a Java project in a SVN repository and I need to export a documentation using all my old commits.

How can I do this?

Comment: `svn co -r "{2014-01-01}" http://example.com/myproject` and then generate javadoc the usual way.

Comment: What does this documentation need to consist of? Is it coming from the commit messages or file content itself (JavaDoc)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to compose a set of documentation outlining all of the messages from your commits, you can use [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

```
svn log /path/to/Java/Project
```

You can add the `--verbose` switch if you want to list out what files are modified in each of said commits in the log.

Whenever I do something like this, I usually output it to a text file so that I can simply copy and paste it into a document so I'll do something like:

```
svn log /path/to/Java/Project --verbose > /path/to/output.txt
```

Which writes it to a convenient text file for you.